# Find IP with Batch

Tags: batch, ip, batch-file, cmd.exe

I need to use a command of some sort to find the external ip of the user of my batch file. I have tried many methods but I need the batch file to recognise the ip as a variable of some sort so it can use it.
Any one got answers

Comment: What do you mean by `external ip`? The IP of that PC on your **internal network** or the external IP on **the internet**?

Comment: I mean the ip the internet would see. Like if you go to http://www.whatsmyip.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never knew about BITSAdmin.

But I found this in the manual:

> BITSAdmin is deprecated and is not guaranteed to be available in
>   future versions of Windows.

You could also do it without BITSadmin (and with a little help from powershell) :

```
@echo off
set ip=
powershell.exe -Command (New-Object net.webclient).downloadstring('http://myexternalip.com/raw') > tempfile
set /p ip=<tempfile
del tempfile
echo %ip%
```

You could also do it without the tempfile (but then it gets a little bit more complicated)

**Edit**:
This is the version without a tempfile:

```
@echo off
set ip=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell.exe -Command ^(New-Object net.webclient^).downloadstring^('http://myexternalip.com/raw'^)') do @set ip=%%a
echo %ip%
```

**Edit2**:
I wasn't really happy with the speed.
Here is a version which is much much faster (almost instantaneously):

```
@echo off
set ip=
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('%windir%\system32\nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com 2^> nul ^| find "Address" ^| find ^/V "208.67.222.222"') do set ip=%%a
echo %ip%
```